# Ansible task to start server not completing

Tags: apt, ansible, kibana

I'm using ansible to setup my ubuntu machine with an ELK server, however I need to install an older version of kibana (5.2.2).

Originally I tried using the `apt` module and the tried something like `- apt: name=kibana=5.2.2 state=present force=yes` but apt couldn't find the version number. Now I'm trying the manual way by downloading, installing it and starting the server.

The problem I'm running into though is that when I tell ansible to run `cd /home/ubuntu/kibana-5.2.2-linux-x86_64/; ./bin/kibana;` it hangs indefinitely and never continues to the next task.

Is there a way to install kibana=5.2.2 through apt that I'm missing or is it possible to run the kibana package I downloaded manually in the background (similar to `sudo service kibana restart`) so that I can continue with the remaining playbook?

Comment: The `name=kibana=5.2.2` syntax works for me. Is that version available in your repos? `apt-cache madison kibana`

Comment: when I run `sudo apt-cache madison kibana` manually I get `N: Unable to locate package kibana`

Comment: nevermind @MarkWagner I just needed to run a `apt-get update` first, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APT ansible module uses the underling apt tools.  It can only install versions that are defined in sources for the distrobution/release you are running on your system.  It can't just install arbitrary versions.

If you can't use `apt-get` to install a given version, then you can't use the ansible apt module to install that version.  Like Mark mentioned in a comment,  you can use the `apt-cache madison kibana` command to see the versions available given your currently defined sources for your release.